# Cannot install OpenSSL with Chocolatey

Tags: openssl, chocolatey

I am trying to install openssl with Chocolatey. What this message is supposed to mean?

> Write-Error : OpenSSL.Light did not finish successfully.
>
> ...
>
> Write-Error : Package 'OpenSSL.Light v1.0.1.20140411' did not install successfully: Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."

I have installed a few utilities by now, but this one (OpenSSL.Light) won't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Are *OpenSSL.Light* and *OpenSSL* the same product? Or is someone doing something clever with *OpenSSL.Light*?

Comment: *"The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found"* could indicate the use of self-authenticating URLs to verify the package (like Python uses). See Gutmann's [Engineering Security](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/book.pdf), page 356.

Comment: The same product, but different name when it is installed with Chocolatey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you download the Chocolatey Package for OpenSSL.Light from the [Chocolatey Package Page](http://chocolatey.org/packages/OpenSSL.Light) and open it in the [Nuget Package Explorer](http://npe.codeplex.com/), you will see the following:

[image: OpenSSL PowerShell Script]

The url and url64bit variables are the URL's that are used by Chocolatey to perform the installation on your PC, based on the processor architecture.  If you try to access either of these URL's you will find that they result in an HTTP 404.

It is likely that when this package was created, these URL's worked correctly, however, "something" has since changed on the website that means that they no longer work.

In these situations, there is an established triage process for dealing with packages that are no longer working.  You can find details of this [here](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/wiki/PackageTriageProcess).

Perhaps the quickest way to getting this fixed would be to issue a pull request to IrisStyle, one of the current maintainers of the package.  You can find his Github Repository [here](https://github.com/Iristyle/ChocolateyPackages).  If you do proceed down this route, and you don't hear anything back, then please refer to the triage process described earlier.

Answer (score 1):

This means there is an error with the package itself. It appears that it is trying to download OpenSSL.Light from the distribution source, but can't because the file doesn't exist, thus the 404. Please use the Contact Maintainers form on the package page of [chocolatey.org](http://chocolatey.org/packages/OpenSSL.Light) to let them know the package is broken.